# Cross reference terraform module for AWS

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have 2 different terraform git repo one has my base code for vpc and structure looks like this
I am using s3 backend

```
gitrepo:vpc
    main.tf
    output.tf
    variables.tf
```

this baseline code is developed by infrastructure team where I don't have permission

I have another git repo for my code as

```
gitrepo:ec2
    main.tf
    output.tf
    variable.tf
```

my `vpc` is already created and I want to use the output values in my ec2 development
how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no write permissions for the other Terraform module where the VPC is managed, and therefore cannot add an output to pass from your root module to the declared `ec2` module, then you will need to use the [aws_vpc datasource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/vpc). Assuming a block of `data "aws_vpc" "this" {...}`, then you can use this within your `ec2` module via the exported attribute `data.aws_vpc.this.id`.